# How to create instruction in function without basic block by LLVM C++ API?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to insert instructions into function without basic block, for example:

```
define void @_Z2f2v() nounwind {
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %b = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %a, align 4
  %1 = load i32* %a, align 4
  %2 = icmp sgt i32 %1, 0
  ret void
}
```

But I read LLVM document, all C++ API I have are:

```
BasicBlock *bb = BasicBlock::Create(...);
irBuilder.setInsertPoint(bb);
irBuilder.CreateXXXInst(...);
```

or

```
Instruction *inst = new XXXInst(..., Instruction *insertBefore);
Instruction *inst = new XXXInst(..., BasicBlock *insertAtEnd);
```

It seems that I must create a BasicBlock at the beginning of a function.

How could I create instruction into function without BasicBlock by C++ API ?

Comment: It needs no BasicBlock, all it needs is a location to insert instructions at.

Comment: what location should I use ? would you please give me a short example ?

Comment: Any instruction is a location in itself, as you can infer from the "insertBefore" argument name. Also, you can use an existing instruction as argument to `setInsertPoint`.

Comment: @oakad, would you please tell me, which existing instruction I could get after I create a function by `llvm::Function::Create(...)` ? Or do you mean `llvm::Function` itself is an instruction ?

Comment: Ok, seems you do need an actual `BasicBlock` after all. Would not `Function::getEntryBlock` give you the correct one for your needs?

Comment: Instructions definitely need a basic block. However: Why would one wanty to avoid having a basic block? What's the real problem here?

Comment: @arnt, curiosity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to insert instructions into function without basic block, for example:
>
> ```
> define void @_Z2f2v() nounwind {
>   %a = alloca i32, align 4
>   %b = alloca i32, align 4
>   store i32 2, i32* %a, align 4
>   %1 = load i32* %a, align 4
>   %2 = icmp sgt i32 %1, 0
>   ret void
> }
> ```

That function contains exactly one basic block, not zero. To create a function like that, you add all of your instructions to the function's entry block.

> How could I create instruction into function without BasicBlock by C++ API ?

You can't - neither using the C++ API nor any other way. Every instruction has to be part of a basic block by definition.

Basic blocks are the nodes in the CFG, so if you had an instruction without a basic block, it would not be part of the CFG and could therefore never be executed, which would be pointless.